# Loading an Express/Angular 5 app hosed on Google Cloud for the first time throws "Not Found" on browser

Tags: angular, express, google-cloud-platform, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

So I have an express app that is serving up a static angular 5 app with service workers to the Google Cloud, and for some reason the first time I load up the app on anything other than the index route "/", the page displays "Not Found".

So my route "/login/signin" won't load, or anything else, until I first go to the "/" route, then everything loads correctly. This only happens once on whichever browser I'm using, then it works fine after that.

I added wildcard routes to my express side, since I thought that might be the problem, but still doesn't work. My only other guess would be something to do with the service worker and its caching.

Or it could have something to do with security settings in the google cloud app settings, I'm not really sure.

[image: example of 'not found']

Here's my express app.ts file, it's pretty basic.

app.ts

```
import debug = require('debug');
import express = require('express');
import path = require('path');

import api from './routes/api';

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api', api);

// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('/public/index.html');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err['status'] = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use((err: any, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(err['status'] || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use((err: any, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.set('port', process.env.port || 8080);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

The only other thing I think that would be useful might be my routing module in Angular

app.routing.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {AdminModule} from '../../pages/main/admin/admin.module';
import {HomeComponent, HomeModule} from '../../pages/main/home/home.module';
import {LoginComponent, LoginModule, SigninComponent, SignupComponent} from '../../pages/login';
import {MainComponent} from '../../core/main';
import {NotFoundComponent} from '../../core/not-found';

import {AuthGuardService as AuthGuard} from '../services/guards/auth.guard.service';
import {RoleGuardService as RoleGuard} from '../services/guards/role.guard.service';
import {LoginGuardService as LoginGuard} from '../services/guards/login.guard.service';

import {ProfileComponent} from '../../pages/main/profile/profile.component';
import {GuardsModule} from '../../core/services/guards';


export const admin = 'app/pages/main/admin/admin.module#AdminModule';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard], data: { state: 'login' },
  children: [
    { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent, data: { state: 'signin' }},
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent, data: { state: 'signup' }},
  ]},
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { state: 'main' },
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { state: 'home' }},
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, data: { state: 'profile' }},
      {
        path: 'admin', loadChildren: admin, canActivate: [RoleGuard],
        data: {
          expectedRole: 'ADMIN_USER',
          state: 'admin'
        }
      },
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]},
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      HomeModule,
      LoginModule,
      AdminModule,
      GuardsModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Edit 1

So I figured out it was the service worker, but I still don't know what's causing it

ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to add `patterns` to your service worker config file and include glob URLs. See [this link](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config) for more info

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot!